# Accessing an object with the corresponding field value

Tags: java

I am new to java and am struggling with removing an object when given a value of its field.

For example, if we have something like

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String studentId;

    public void createStudent(String name, int age, String studentId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public void removeStudent(String studentId) {
        
    }
}
```

where I am given a studentId and want to remove the student object with the same studentId, how would I do this?

I've searched up on google but nothing really gave me a clear answer. Is getClass() the right way to do it?

Comment: Well, in order to remove a student, you first have to store it somewhere. For example in an array or a list or a map. The method to remove it then depends on the data structure used to store it in the first place.

Comment: Remove the object from where? Do you have a list of `Student`s? Then call the list's [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) method. For that to work, you should probably implement [hashCode and equals](https://ahdak.github.io/blog/effective-java-part-2/), or you need to know the Student's position in the list to remove by index (position). You could iterate over the list, compare the `Student.studentId` to the one you want to remove, and then call `remove` on the list.

Comment: You didn't specify what you're "removing the object" *FROM*.  A List?  An array? Something else? One effective way is to store your objects in a Java [Dictionary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html), e.g. a HashMap: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp.  A less efficient, "brute force" method is to iterate through all your objects (however they're stored), checking each one's name in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Use "remove" method of List to remove Student object.
Suppose you are storing Student objects in the list called "students".
You can delete student object like this: -

```
for(Student student: students){
  if(student.getStudentId().equals(studentId)){
    students.remove(student);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will generally fail as you're modifying a collection while iterating over it. It will be fine for *some* collections, but many will fail.

Answer (score 0):

What are you meaning by removing? Remove it from memory? Then just make it null:

```java
   Student st = new Student(); //creates student
   st.createStudent("st1", 20, "11"); //sets variables to fields (better do this in constructor)
   st = null; // make reference to st object null, it is now eligible for Garbage Collection
```

Keep in mind java has not something like `delete` in C++, whenever variable unreferenced GC collects it e.g. clears it's space from memory.

Comment: Setting a variable to null only means that *that* variable won't stop the object from being garbage collected. Separately, it seems more likely that the OP is actually considering a collection of students somewhere.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he wants to delete object from memory, because he didn't specify any array or collection.

Comment: I *suspect* that was just an oversight - and that they may just generally be a bit confused. But the fact that they want to remove the student *by student ID* at least *suggests* a collection somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

To remove a Student object based on a given `studentId`, you need to have a data structure to store the Student objects. One commonly used data structure for this purpose is a list or an array. Here's an example of how you can implement the `removeStudent` method:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Iterator;
 import java.util.List;

public class StudentManagement {
private List<Student> students;

public StudentManagement() {
    this.students = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void createStudent(String name, int age, String studentId) {
    Student student = new Student(name, age, studentId);
    students.add(student);
}

public void removeStudent(String studentId) {
    Iterator<Student> iterator = students.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Student student = iterator.next();
        if (student.getStudentId().equals(studentId)) {
            iterator.remove();
            break; // Assuming studentId is unique, no need to continue the loop
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StudentManagement management = new StudentManagement();
    management.createStudent("John", 18, "12345");
    management.createStudent("Alice", 20, "54321");

    System.out.println("Before removal:");
    management.printStudents();

    management.removeStudent("12345");

    System.out.println("After removal:");
    management.printStudents();
}

public void printStudents() {
    for (Student student : students) {
        System.out.println(student.getName() + " - " + student.getStudentId());
    }
}
}
```

In this example, the `StudentManagement` class maintains a list (`students`) to store the `Student` objects. The `removeStudent` method iterates over the list using an `Iterator` and checks if the `studentId` of each `Student` object matches the given `studentId`. If a match is found, the student is removed from the list using the `Iterator`'s `remove` method.

The `main` method demonstrates the usage of the `StudentManagement` class by creating some `Student` objects, printing them before removal, removing a student with the specified `studentId`, and printing the list again to verify the removal.

Note: The `Student` class in the example is assumed to have appropriate getter methods (`getName()`, `getStudentId()`) for retrieving the values of its fields.

**N.B. : this is AI generated answer.**

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to place both of those methods, within a different class.

The *Student* class is the container for the data.

```java
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String studentId;
}
```

> *"... remove the student object with the same studentId, how would I do this? ..."*

Here is an example; I'm not sure if this is the exact requirement.

I presume that there is an array of *Student* objects—or most likely, a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)*.

You will need to traverse the *List* with a *loop*, and remove the matching element.

```java
class StudentUtil {
    static List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();

    static void createStudent(String name, int age, String studentId) {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.name = name;
        student.age = age;
        student.studentId = studentId;
        list.add(student);
    }

    static void removeStudent(String studentId) {
        Iterator<Student> iterator = list.iterator();
        Student student;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            student = iterator.next();
            if (student.studentId.equals(studentId)) {
                iterator.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a usage example.

```java
StudentUtil.createStudent("nameA", 1, "abc123");
StudentUtil.createStudent("nameB", 2, "def456");
StudentUtil.createStudent("nameC", 3, "ghi789");

StudentUtil.removeStudent("abc123");
```